# How do I control the workspace sessions timeout message (ORACLE APEX 20.1)

Tags: session, oracle-apex

While I’m working on ORACLE APEX 20.1, usually within one hour, in the middle of coding or designing, the annoying popup modal appears saying ‘Session timeout will expire on XX’. This happens wither the session is ideal or in during coding.
I’m not talking about running applications, I’m talking about doing some jobs on SQL Workshop or Page Design.
Is there anyway to define appropriate session time or to keep the session life as long as I’m doing my job?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe this is a bug. The solution is to just hit "Cancel" on that message and it will allow you to to proceed.

Comment: True, but the message still pop up continuously.

Comment: Have you tried to configuring session timeout for your workspace ?